# How to stop "only secure content is displayed" post-SSL update? CRM 2011 OnPrem

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

We recently updated a CRM 2011 on premise instance to use SSL i.e. https. I wasn't involved in the server part of the updates. Everything works fine except at initial login, IE displays the "Only secure content is displayed" warning. If I look at the source of the page, I see a bunch of http://... refs to microsoft sites for example. So presumably that is the source of the issue. The landing page doesn't have any custom "stuff" on it, all OOTB.

What can we do to get around this? I know we could change an IE setting but that isn't an option for us. Is there some IIS voodoo tthat we can use? Surely we don't have to go through all http refs in the web app and change them?

Comment: Setting up IFD would wrap everything up in HTTPS nicely, is that an option for you ?

Comment: @Alex, can you elaborate on what you mean? The current user base is all within our corporate firewalls and likely to stay that way for a while

Answer (score 0):

> I know we could change an IE setting but that isn't an option for us. Is there some IIS voodoo tthat we can use?

Man, I wish. Even when we get HTML e-mails with images in them we get that message.

Because it's a security setting and it's the browser causing the error message and not the server, there really isn't much we can do about it on the server side except for serving all content over SSL.

That being said, it seems really strange that out of the box content is giving you errors.

It's *possible* [that using a re-write rule](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/) on IIS will stop this from happening, as all the content on your server is capable of being served in SSL, but CRM is not requesting it - I'm just hoping that this doesn't break any customization and links to external services.

Comment: Thanks for info. I will talk to server admins about re-write rules as its not my area of expertize. Do you know if it's possible for a single CRM server to handle both http AND https traffic? Like, could it be setup such that browser clients could access crm via https and outlook clients access the same crm via http? I'm not an expert on this by any means and I have read conflicting answers about this

Comment: [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2502671) ("For Cause 4" section), for example, seems to suggest we can have BOTH a single http AND https binding. Would that mean the 1 crm server is accessible via http AND https?

Comment: From a purely server point of view, yes - you can simultaneously serve ssl and regular http. Id recommend sticking with ssl as if you give people the option, it eliminates most of the benefits.

Comment: good to know thanks. We had a situation where we needed the IE clients to use SSL but needed to buy time to transition the outlook clients. Still not sure if both http & https at the same time is supported...